# Merging dictionary pairs in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, structure

Input:

```
[{'name': 'pc1'},
{'data': [[20, 400], [30, 450]]},
{'name': 'pc2'},
{'data': [[40, 525], [50, 600], [70, 680]]},
{'name': 'pc3'},
{'data': [[80, 700], [90, 980]]}]
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
[{'name': 'pc1', "data": [[20,400]. [30,450]]},
{'name': 'pc2', "data": [[40, 525], [50, 600], [70, 680]]},
etc.
```

I can't seem to come up with an elegant way to do this while also retaining the exact structure I'm looking for. It's vital that the "data" values are a list of lists.

I'm using Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Python 3.5+

Using syntax from [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/):

```
>>> [{**x, **y} for x, y in zip(l[::2], l[1::2])]
[{'data': [[20, 400], [30, 450]], 'name': 'pc1'}, ...]
```

#### Older Python:

```
>>> [dict(x, **y) for x, y in zip(l[::2], l[1::2])]
[{'data': [[20, 400], [30, 450]], 'name': 'pc1'}, ...]
```

Comment: Sorry about that - I'm using 2.7

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this. Should work in 2.6+, maybe older

```
original = [{'name': 'pc1'},
            {'data': [[20, 400],
                      [30, 450]]},
            {'name': 'pc2'},
            {'data': [[40, 525],
                      [50, 600],
                      [70, 680]]},
            {'name': 'pc3'},
            {'data': [[80, 700],
                      [90, 980]]}]
new = []
for d1,d2 in zip(original[::2], original[1::2]):
    d1.update(d2)
    new.append(d1)
```

vaultah edited his answer to include python2, and I didn't know you could do dict(dict1,**dict2),  I like his answer better, but I'll just leave this up as an alternative.

Also, Mike Müller's answer(and comment) that uses copy reminded me that you could just do it in place., and that my code was modifying the original variable. so you could do this:

```
original = [{'name': 'pc1'},
            {'data': [[20, 400],
                      [30, 450]]},
            {'name': 'pc2'},
            {'data': [[40, 525],
                      [50, 600],
                      [70, 680]]},
            {'name': 'pc3'},
            {'data': [[80, 700],
                      [90, 980]]}]
for d1,d2 in zip(original[::2], original[1::2]):
    d1.update(d2)
    original.remove(d2)
```

and the original list would then equal what you wanted without creating a new variable.  But I still like vaultah's one liner better

Comment: This modifies `original`.

Comment: I realized that when I saw your answer, and updated. Good eye.

Answer (score 0):

This is about as close I can come to clean solution

```
values = [{'name': 'pc1'},
{'data': [[20, 400], [30, 450]]},
{'name': 'pc2'},
{'data': [[40, 525], [50, 600], [70, 680]]},
{'name': 'pc3'},
{'data': [[80, 700], [90, 980]]}]

groupings = [{'name' : values[g]['name'], 'data' : values[g + 1]['data']} for g in xrange(0, len(data) - 1, 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> [dict(*zip(d1.items(), d2.items())) for d1, d2  in zip(orig[::2], orig[1::2])]
[{'data': [[20, 400], [30, 450]], 'name': 'pc1'},
 {'data': [[40, 525], [50, 600], [70, 680]], 'name': 'pc2'},
 {'data': [[80, 700], [90, 980]], 'name': 'pc3'}]
```

where:

```
>>> orig = [{'name': 'pc1'},
            {'data': [[20, 400], [30, 450]]},
            {'name': 'pc2'},
            {'data': [[40, 525], [50, 600], [70, 680]]},
            {'name': 'pc3'},
            {'data': [[80, 700], [90, 980]]}]
```